# Perl error - cant call the "getPageContent" on undefined value?

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-extraction, cam-pdf

Hi im trying to extract the content of pdf file but im facing the above problem 
 my code is

```
use PDF;

use CAM::PDF;

use CAM::PDF::PageText;

my $file = "s.pdf"; 
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($file); 
 my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContent(1);
 print CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
```

Im getting error " getPageContent(1)" here . what went wrong in my code

Comment: Please keep in mind that CAM::PDF::PageText is just a crude heuristic! It's basically rendering the PDF in memory and looking at which characters end up close to each other. Don't expect it to produce quality output on arbitrary PDFs.

Comment: @ChrisDolan  is there anyway to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this

```
my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree($_);
```

Comment: Or just use `$pdf->getPageText($pagenum)` which is a convenience function to wrap the call to `getPageContentTree` and `CAM::PDF::PageText`. (I'm the CAM::PDF author)